# How to shorten this code or make it more efficient?

Tags: optimization, godot, gdscript

I want to know if there is any more efficient/shorter way to give the same result.
The function get_action_strength(action) returns a boolean if the key is pressed,
Thanks.

```
var degValue = 0

if (Input.get_action_strength("move_forward")):
    degValue = 0
    if (Input.get_action_strength("move_right")):
        degValue += -45
    if (Input.get_action_strength("move_left")):
        degValue += 45
elif (Input.get_action_strength("move_backward")):
    degValue = 180
    if (Input.get_action_strength("move_right")):
        degValue -= -45
    if (Input.get_action_strength("move_left")):
        degValue -= 45
else:
    if (Input.get_action_strength("move_right")):
        degValue = -90
    if (Input.get_action_strength("move_left")):
        degValue = 90
```

Comment: So desired possible outputs are 0°, 45°, 90°, 135°, 180°, 225°, 270°, 315° ?

Comment: Yes, based on the inputs booleans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function get_action_strength(action) returns a boolean if the key is pressed

No, it doesn't. [`get_action_strength`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-get-action-strength) returns float. You can use that to your advantage.

You can do this:

```
var x = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
var y = Input.get_action_strength("move_forward") - Input.get_action_strength("move_backward")
```

Furthermore, [`atan2`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-atan2) will return `0` if the parameters are `0`. *That is one of the benefit of using `atan2` instead of `atan`: You don't have to worry about a division by `0`.* Thus, you don't need to check if `x` and `y` are not `0`, just use them.

*By the way, `y` comes before `x` in `atan2`.*

One more thing, there is a [`rad2deg`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-rad2deg) function, if you have radians and want degrees:

```
var x = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
var y = Input.get_action_strength("move_forward") - Input.get_action_strength("move_backward")
var degValue = rad2deg(atan2(y, x))
```

*If you really want, you can inline the variables, and it would be a one-liner.*

---

Ah, sorry, I may have misunderstood. You want it to be discrete, right? You want [`ceil`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-ceil):

```
var x = ceil(Input.get_action_strength("move_right")) - ceil(Input.get_action_strength("move_left"))
var y = ceil(Input.get_action_strength("move_forward")) - ceil(Input.get_action_strength("move_backward"))
var degValue = rad2deg(atan2(y, x))
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed my mistake, thought it was boolean. This second solution is definetely the best one, can fit into single line, thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Second branch of if's can be changed to smth like that:

`degValue += -45 * int(Input.get_action_strength("move_right")) + 45 * int(Input.get_action_strength("move_left"))`

When the value is False and you convert it to int, it becomes 0, and the multiply result is 0. So only one of the values is added.

Also, if the question is tagged 'python', why are you declaring variable with 'var' keyword? =)

Comment: Thanks, that is better, the code is now 9 lines instead of 17 lines. The code is actually gdscript but very similar to python so I used python tag because of the bigger community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vectors and compute the angle from its components:

```
motion_vec_x = 0
motion_vec_y = 0

if (Input.get_action_strength("move_forward")):
    motion_vec_y = 1
if (Input.get_action_strength("move_backward")):
    motion_vec_y = -1
if (Input.get_action_strength("move_left")):
    motion_vec_x = -1
if (Input.get_action_strength("move_right")):
    motion_vec_x = 1

degValue = None
if abs(motion_vec_x) > 0 or abs(motion_vec_y) > 0:
    degValue = np.arctan2(motion_vec_x, motion_vec_y) / np.pi * 180

print(degValue
```

This will yield (depending on the arctan2 implementation) 0° for up, negative degrees for a vector tilted to the left and positive values for the vector tilted to the right. Pointing straight down is going to be 180°. You will easily be able to convert this to any angle values you need and deem fit.

Comment: Perfect ! I didn't know about arctan2, I managed to shorten this into 4 lines, I guess I can't get shorter. Thanks you.